# Keras model not using GPU on ai platform training

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have a simple `Keras` model that I am submitting to Google Cloud AI Platform training, and would like to make use of a GPU for processing.

The job submits and completes successfully. 
Looking at the usage statistics, the GPU never goes beyond `0%` utilization.  However, CPU usage increases as training progresses.

Any idea on what might be wrong in making my model work with a GPU? 
Are there any ways that I might be able to troubleshoot a situation like this?

config.yaml

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
```

I am using runtime version `1.13`, which comes with tensorflow already installed.  My additional required packages in my `setup.py` include:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['google-api-core==1.14.2',
                     'google-cloud-core==1.0.3',
                     'google-cloud-logging==1.12.1',
                     'google-cloud-storage==1.18.0',
                     'gcsfs==0.2.3',
                     'h5py==2.9.0',
                     'joblib==0.13.2',
                     'numpy==1.16.4',
                     'pandas==0.24.2',
                     'protobuf==3.8.0',
                     'scikit-learn==0.21.2',
                     'scipy==1.3.0',
                     'Keras==2.2.4',
                     'Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0',
                     ]
```

Looking at logs, it looks like the GPU is found

```
master-replica-0 Found device 0 with properties:  master-replica-0 
master-replica-0 name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235 master-replica-0
```

Update:

The model is using a GPU, but is under-utilized.

Within `AI Platform`, the `utilization graphs` in the Job overview page are about 5 minutes behind the activity displayed in the logs.
As a result, your logs could show an epoch being processed, but the utilization graphs can still show `0% utilization`.

How I resolved -

- I am using the `fit_generator` function
- I set `multiprocessing=true, queue_length=10, workers=5`.  I am currently tweaking these parameters to determine what works best, however I see ~30% utilization on my GPU now.

Comment: What type of data read and model are you using? Low GPU utilization could be due attributed to several reasons but most likely you're having a bottleneck when reading the training data. As your GPU has processed a batch it requires more data. Depending on your implementation this can cause the GPU to wait for the CPU to load more data resulting in a lower GPU usage and also a longer training time.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563418/low-gpu-usage-by-keras-tensorflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777871/does-tensorflow-use-all-of-the-hardware-on-the-gpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is using a GPU, but is under-utilized.

Within `AI Platform`, the `utilization graphs` in the Job overview page are about 5 minutes behind the activity displayed in the logs.
As a result, your logs could show an epoch being processed, but the utilization graphs can still show `0% utilization`.

How I resolved -

- I am using the `fit_generator` function
- I set `multiprocessing=true, queue_length=10, workers=5`.  I am currently tweaking these parameters to determine what works best, however I see ~30% utilization on my GPU now.

Comment: Can u move this to original question?

Comment: @user260826 Out of curiosity, why did you edit to format my question and answer -  Are the guidelines that outline the type of information that should be highlighted?

Comment: TBH normally just code or keywords, I did highlight the key details for readability. This is a good post I found regards this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit